Python replacing words in string using dictionary when one of the "words" is a letter?
I am working on the following problem for an edx course:
#For this question, your goal is to decipher a text message to plain English.
#You can ignore grammar, you're just translating common text slang into
#normal words.
#
#Write a function called text_deciphered. text_deciphered should have two
#parameters: a string representing a text message, and a dictionary representing
#a set of known abbreviations. In this dictionary, the keys are the English words
#and the values are the abbreviated words.
#
#Return a translated version of the string, replacing the abbreviated words with
#the real English words.
#
#For example:
#text_message = "Hey, wat r our plans for tn"
#abbrevs = {"what": "wat", "are": "r", "tonight": "tn"}
#text_deciphered(text_message, abbrevs) -> "Hey, what are our plans for tonight"
#Write your code here!


#Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
#You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
#function with different inputs.
#
#If your function works correctly, this will originally
#print: Hey, what are our plans for tonight
text_message = "Hey, wat r our plans for tn"
abbrevs = {"what": "wat", "are": "r", "tonight": "tn"}
print(text_deciphered(text_message, abbrevs))

The code I wrote is this:
def text_deciphered(text_string, abb_dict):
    words= text_string.split()
    for word in words:
        for key, value in abb_dict.items():
            if word == value:
                text_string= text_string.replace(word, key)
    return text_string

This is returning:
"Hey, what are ouare plans foare tonight"

I can see that the problem is that it is replacing the letter "r" wherever it appears with "are" but I can't figure out how to tell it to only count "r" as a word to be replaced when it's followed by spaces on either side. Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

where and how is text_deciphered defined?

Your primary problem is your use of the replace method on the input string. You need to modify your code so you are only replacing the word you're are iterating over.
Your implementation is also inefficient as you are iterating over the dictionary for every word.
def text_deciphered(text_string, abb_dict):
    words = text_string.split()
    abb_dict_reversed = {}
    for k, v in abb_dict.items():
        abb_dict_reversed[v] = k
    
    for i in range(len(words)):
        correct_word = abb_dict_reversed.get(words[i], words[i])
        words[i] = correct_word
        
    return " ".join(words)

text_message = "Hey, wat r our plans for tn"
abbrevs = {"what": "wat", "are": "r", "tonight": "tn"}
print(text_deciphered(text_message, abbrevs))

The above reverses the dictionary to allow you to quickly look up the mappings, and also will only modify the word being iterated.

You can't do a straightforward text substitution on the original string, for exactly this reason.
Instead, you could create a new string to hold the translated message, building it up word by word as you translate the input message.
Also, you don't need to iterate over the abbreviations dictionary.  You know what word you're looking for, so just check for it directly.
translated_message = ""
for word in words:
    # if this word has a translation, use it
    if word in abb_dict:
        translated_message += abb_dict[word]
    # otherwise this word has no translation
    else:
        translated_message += word
    # add a space between words
    translated_message += " "
return translated_message


One-liner:
def text_deciphered(text_string: str, abb_dict: dict[str, str]) -> str:
    return " ".join(abb_dict.get(word, word) for word in text_string.split())

However I've changed the order of the abbrevs dict, it's reversed (keys are values and values are keys) like so:
abbrevs = {'wat': 'what', 'r': 'are', 'tn': 'tonight'}

